# What is the difference among App CPU, System CPU and User CPU

Tags: manual-testing, performance, android, mobile

What is the difference between **App** CPU, **System** CPU and **User** CPU?

I am testing a mobile app and I found these 3 terms, but I could not get an exact answer anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

These terms are probably used to mean the following:

- **System CPU** - the percentage of CPU capacity the entire system is using.
- **User CPU** - the percentage of CPU capacity the current user is using. This will be less than the System CPU and will include whatever apps are currently running, but not the operating system.
- **App CPU** - the percentage of CPU capacity the target App is using.